# Please clarify the use of "=>" in MVC Razor syntax?

Tags: c#, lambda

Please clarify the use of `=>` in MVC Razor. For example, in the context of a statement such as:

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.AnswerText)
```

Comment: It doesn't mean equal or bigger than, it points out that m refers to the model, specific to the AnswerText property.

Answer (score 1):

=> is a lambda expression. Basically it's short hand for selecting the value of one of the parameters in your model.
For instance if you have

```
@model YourDomain.Foo.Models.Bar
```

and in your Bar model you have a string called UserName
then using @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName) 
will display the value of the user name in the model. ie (John Smith)
When using a LabelFor however instead of it displaying the value of the Model parameter it displays the name of the model parameter so in your example where you are using

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.AnswerText)
```

your resulting display will be AnswerText

Answer (score 0):

In that context (and any other), it's a [lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx).

You need to use a lambda expression, you can't just call the method with Model.AnswerText. If you use Model.AnswerText it would just work as a regular parameter to a method. When you use a lambda expression as a parameter, the method can look at the model metadata, to get a name (for the html element) and the value (along with other things).

Answer (score 0):

It's a lambda operator, just like anywhere else in C#. In this case LabelFor is an extension method with parameter expression that returns model property value (right side).

Answer (score -2):

It's as simple as saying `=>` implies that the word preceding the `=>` is a placeholder variable.

More info [here](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1397803) and [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/lambda)

Comment: Thanks for the links.  The second link especially explains it well